# create a site map xml from sql database and store it in site folder on server using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I need to create a sitemap xml for google from my database and store it on server using C#. This is all I got so far.. (help me how to retrieve this xml file and store on server with a file name xxxx.xml using c#)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SitemapXML]
(@url NVARCHAR(500) = '', )
AS
BEGIN
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
    (
        DEFAULT 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
    )
    SELECT  
        @url + '/default.aspx?page=' + CAST(a.id AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS 'location',
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), a.page_date, 110) AS 'lastmodified',      
    FROM    
        tbl_mytable a WITH (NOLOCK)
    FOR XML PATH('url'), ROOT('urlroot')
END
```

But this is reading very few pages with their urls into the xml and breaking in the middle around at id of 10. And not closing the xml tags properly. Please help.

Thanks

Here is the output:

```
<urlroot xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=1</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=2</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=3</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=4</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=5</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=6</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=7</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=8</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=9</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=10</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=11</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod></url>
<url><location>xxx.com/default.aspx?page=12</location><lastmod>01-01-2012</lastmod>
```

It is breaking at page 12 but i have so many pages in the database table.

Comment: Can you **show us** a sample output (that *doesn't close XML tags properly* as you claim) ? And can you show us what your database table contains?

Comment: does google need an actual file, or simply a url that points to a resource that returns a sitemap? you may be able to omit a physical file and just query the database returning the xml to google.

Comment: Edited my question with output result

Comment: Check this https://www.code-labs.dev/generating-xml-sitemaps-sql-server/